# Filtering previous dropdown lists in a SharePoint 2007 web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have four controls; three DropDownList boxes and regular list box. I am gathering the following SharePoint data for each:

> DropDownList1 = Web Applications
>
> DropDownList2 = Site Collections of DropDownList1 selection
>
> DropDownList3 = Sites in the site collection from selection in DropdownList2
>
> Listbox = Document Libraries from selection in DropDownList3

Since each is a function of one another, how do I solve this in C#. I want to render them in a web part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have to do is populate the web application dropdown on webpart load .
enable postback true for all three dropdowns.
and create handler on selected index change for all three dropdowns.
on selected index change of webapplication populate sitecollection dropdown
and on selectedindex change of sitecollection dropdown populate web dropdown
and on selected index change of web populate listbox with document libraries